# Get $x$ in terms of $t$ or vice versa

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , $f(t,x) =t+x+e^{x-t}$
>
> Solve $f(t,x)$ = $c$.

Comment: Usual question: Where are you stuck?

Comment: How to start? It seems hard to find $x$ in terms of $t$ or $t$ in terms of $x$

Comment: It seems that this will involve the Lambert $\mathrm{W}$-function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as  Workaholic commented, the solutions are given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). For $t+x+e^{x-t}=c$,  the solutions are $$x=-W\left(e^{c-2 t}\right)+c-t$$ $$t=W\left(-e^{2 x-c}\right)+c-x$$ Lambert function $W(z)$ being such that $z=W(z)\, e^{W(z)}$.

The Wikipedia page gives good examples.

In fact, any equation which can write $A+Bx+C\log(D+Ex)=0$ has solutions in terms of Lambert function.